# How to define id in POST request using Ravendb

Tags: rest, ravendb

**Hello there**

I'm having a trouble when I try to insert a document into a Ravendb Server which is running in my other computer. I can retrieve documents easily, but when I try to use REST API with POST request I get this error

> "System.ArgumentException","Message":"Query string value 'id' must have a non empty value","Error":"System.ArgumentException: Query string value 'id' must have a non empty value

even though I have my Id defined like this:

{
"id":"adawd",
"name":"genereicname",
"password":"something"
}

Originally I'm making a flutter application but currently I'm just testing the API with Postman.

I messed around with id's (String, int) tried to leave it empty but no luck, does anyone know how to define Id for raven db to send me that sweet 200 response code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation you should use `PUT` to upload a new document or modify an existing one.

See: https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.2/csharp/client-api/rest-api/document-commands/put-documents

[image]

Comment: Neither PUT or POST request don't work. Always get some Id related error...

Comment: Seems that RavenDB is looking for this id to be in the query string, not in the body (or in addition). Look here: https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb/blob/38d47464ef303dc3ce4ccb761f8fd88be5836b95/src/Raven.Server/Documents/Handlers/DocumentHandler.cs#L486